# LOG-END-OFFSET adds up to twice the number of messages in the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

According to [this](https://riptutorial.com/apache-kafka/example/27968/kafka-consumer-groups) log-end-offset for the consumers in a consumer group for a topic should add up to the number of messages in that topic. I have a case where log-end-offset is adding up to twice the number of messages in the topic (log-end-offset adds up to 28 whereas there are only 14 messages in the topic). What are some potential explanations for this?

The current issue I am facing with this jdbc sink connector is that there are there is a bad message at offset 0 i.e. if the connector tries to process it then it will fail due to violating a db constraint. We have been able to work around this by manually moving the connector's consumer offset s.t. it skips over the bad message. Then randomly months later, it tried to go back and process it even though nobody manually asked it to. The two issues seem related - it seems like something is tricking the connector into thinking it needs to reprocess all of the messages in the topic, hence why the log-end-offsets add up to twice the number of messages in the topic.

We are on Confluent 5.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Hi offset is always moving forward even when old messages getting prune / deleted from the topic after configurable retention times / size. So in your case having log end offset of 28 and only 14 messages which are really inside the topic at the moment, is a valid situation.

Comment: Ah gotcha, good thinking. Unfortunately I can confirm though that this is not the case for me since we do not prune or delete messages from this topic.

Comment: Please share the topic configuration and configuration related to retentions and segment,  dynamic configuration on this topic entity as well, maybe some configuration had changed without you knowing, I do not know of any other reason for this to happen, I would a recheck of all the configurations.